# Error while adding Eloquent class to User in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make an eloquent model out of two table, pekerjaan and user. User hasMany pekerjaan and pekerjaan belongsTo User. How do I add eloquent's method to the User class in Laravel? I have an error that shows:

> Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use

Here is my User.php model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent{
    public function pekerjaans(){
        return $this->hasMany(Pekerjaan::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'satker',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

And here is my Pekerjaan.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Pekerjaan extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function penyedia(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Penyedia::class, 'penyedia_id');
   }

   public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it what is the problem:

```
Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use
```

Your problem is you have 2 classes of `User` in your `User.php`. Remove the first `User` class put the function `pekerjaans` to the 2nd `User` class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'satker',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function pekerjaans(){
        return $this->hasMany(Pekerjaan::class);
    }
}
```